# converting a dashed line into multiple lines in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to take a dashed line and quickly turn it into multiple lines, retaining its dash pattern. Maybe I need to get into some kind of scripting? If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Sin, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I think the question is quite unclear, you can get a better answer if you edit your question. As you can see youve allready gotten 2 different iterpretations for your question. Surely you can get a better answer by clarifying. Its by the way also possible to get the stroke expanded (or atleast close) without making the individual segments expanded to closed paths.

Answer (score 3):

There is a extetendScript that can do this effortlessly and precise: [breakDashes.jsx](https://github.com/shspage/illustrator-scripts)

If you take five minutes to learn where to paste scripts into the right folder and then inside Illustrator go to File → Scripts → BreakDashes

*You might also need to sign up to GitHub too in order to download the file.*

Answer (score 2):

Use the options on the **Stroke Panel** to create a dashed line....

[image]

Then choose `Object > Expand Appearance` and then `Object > Expand` to create shapes for each of the dashes.

[image]

Comment: Note that with this solution, the single strokes becomes a series of little rectangles, NOT a series of smaller strokes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily duplicate an object by doing a transform.

You can duplicate an object by going to `object - transform - move`, select the amount you want to move the line. Make sure to click `copy`. You can then do transform again to make more lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you want to have multiple lines, I assume you want to cut your line into multiple separate lines.

You can do that with the **Scissor Tool** (<kbd>C</kbd>). Click with it on the part, where you want to cut your line and it will be separated into two independent lines.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this for the Cricut to upload into Design Space, I wanted to use the dashes as cut marks for a folding line.  To do this efficiently, I needed to make sure the lines ended up as a compound path.  For those facing a similar need, hopefully this will work for you. Note: I am using Illustrator CS6.

Making a dotted single cut using a brush pattern (mine was a very thin line)

1. Object -> Expand appearance
2. Object -> Compound path -> Make

Making a dotted single cut using a dashed stroke
1. Object -> Expand 
2. Object -> Compound path -> Make

Answer (score 0):

To convert a solid line into a series of smaller lines (not paths), use the method described at: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/transform-dashed-lines-into-separate-small-lines/td-p/2876098

I quote the answer given there:

> Correct answer by tolyn_dayana
>
> I know this is an old post. Just to share my method. I found the best
> solution for this problem :
>
> 1- create a single line i.e. 12pt long 1pt thick
>
> 2- make a pattern brush from the line
>
> 3- In pattern brush options dialog box, put 50% in spacing box.
>
> 4- apply the pattern brush to your desired shape.
>
> 5- you can still adjust the gaps in spacing box and hit apply to
> stroke
>
> 6- You can also change stroke weight !
>
> 7- go to object -> expand appearance.
>
> Done !
>
> Hope this will help.
>
> - Tolyn